# Telnet connect to localhost failed on windows subsystem WSL2 Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, putty, windows-subsystem-for-linux, telnet, wsl2

I'm using Windows Subsystem (WSL2) Ubuntu 20.04, trying to run command `telnet localhost 2181`, but only got error message saying

> telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused

Tried the same command on Windows 10, got similar error:

> Could not open connection to the host, on port 2181: Connect failed

So, I have opened 2181 port on Windows firewall, also have tried different solutions found online, none of them worked.

Since the final purpose is just to type `srvr` after the connection in order to validate my Apache Zookeeper is running right, so I started to find an alternative of `telnet` --> PuTTY.

With PuTTY, I did the settings as below, tried both "ssh" and "telnet" as the connection type, but both were showing "connection error"
[image]

**My question is:**

- How can I connect to localhost with `telnet` through WSL2 Ubuntu?
- Or is there any alternative of `telnet` to run on WSL2 Ubuntu?